# Redirecting output to file using fopen_s

Tags: c++, visual-c++, fopen, file-handling

i am trying to output a buffer into a file "z.txt" which is located at my desktop.i am doing in win32 (visual c++)
my syntax for doing so is -

```
  memcpy(HtmlFileContents,&Buffer[location],HtmlFileLength);//i have the contents in HtmlFileContents 
//which i have to display  in the file "z.txt"
                FILE *stream ;
                errno_t err;
                err=fopen_s(&stream, "C:\\Users\\sshekha\\Desktop\\z.txt","w");//err gives error 13
// when in write mode but when in read mode it opens the file   
                if( err == 0 )
                {
                    MessageBox(m_hwndPreview,L" the file is opened ",L"BTN WND",MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox(m_hwndPreview,L" the file is not opened ",L"BTN WND",MB_ICONINFORMATION);

            }
```

could anyone please give idea why it do so ???

Comment: Could you describe what it is doing wrong ?

Comment: And where do you actually *write* the output to the file?

Comment: Joachim right now i am just opening it but even it  is not opening it and eb=ven if i put it read mode it gives dialodbox mentioning "file is opened" but when i see  on debugging it has value stream = 0x000000005c5c76f0 {_ptr=0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> _cnt=0 _base=0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> ...}

Comment: Then it *is* open, and you can write to the file. Don't read to much into the values inside the `stream` structure, as it's supposed to be a "black box".

Comment: No, but these values are when i put"r" instead of "w". i mean in read mode it opens the file but not in write mode(the err gives 13 on debugging on write mode but 0 on read mode)

Comment: Have you even *tried* writing to the file?

Comment: yes i tried to write it adding these 2 lines to previous code- fputs (HtmlFileContents,stream);
    fclose(stream);
but it gives error on debugging that (debug assertion failed) Expression:(stream!=NULL)

Answer (score 1):

If you check an [official reference of errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), you will see that error 13 is `EACCESS` meaning you don't have permission to write to the file.

You need to change the file permissions so you can write to it, and the folders too of course.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the permissions i have cj=hecked properly nor it is open any where and i also closed it properly.i don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Joachim there is a question ? is it necessary that if we output to a file using fputs() then that file must have opened before writting  in read mode only (not write) ??

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT You can't write to a file opened only for reading. As for the permissions, have you checked the folder permissions as well?

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT And you run the program when logged in as user `sshekha`? Clearly there is *something* you don't have permissions for, as that's the error you get.

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT Also try creating the file somewhere else, like the current directory or `C:\Temp`.

Comment: ok let me try ...will tell you soon the result and yes you are right i need ot enter teh passwod when i enter my company's acccount

Comment: yes i have done that also result is same - in read mode it gives stream = 0x000000005bb676f0 {_ptr=0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> _cnt=0 _base=0x0000000000000000 <Bad Ptr> ...} and write mode it go to first condtion of my code above (i mean stream=0)

Comment: @ShekharSinghSHEKHAWAT The contents of the `stream` structure is **not** important. What **is** important is that the pointer is non-null and that `err` is zero, if both of those conditions are true then the file is opened okay.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the file is opened somewhere else (or more specifically not properly closed).

Comment: its not opened anywhere

Comment: Then, why not open/close it with a notepad to be sure that it's properly closed (and viewed as such for the OS) and relaunch your program ?

Comment: yaah done that also. it gives a dialog box on debugging that debugging assertion failed. Expression:(stream!=NULL)